# Rule induction in Isar

Tags: isabelle, isar

I want to do a rule induction in Isabelle/Isar. I find that

```
proof (rule_tac P="λn. f n ≥ n ∧ f n ≥ 1" in f.induct)
```

or

```
proof (rule f.induct[of "λn. f n ≥ n ∧ f n ≥ 1"])
```

do exactly what I want. But how can I write that line using "new style" Isar? As you can see, I'm simply trying to tell Isabelle how to instantiate the `P` variable in the induction rule for my function `f`.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you are already using Isar style as there is no `apply`.

You can also use the syntax `f.induct[where P="λn. f n ≥ n ∧ f n ≥ 1"]`.

Also, often it is not necessary to instantiate `P` manually since unification will give you `P`. Maybe you have to reformulate your goal to achieve this. In Isar style unification also happens after `proof` when you start a `show`, so that is another option to avoid giving it explicitly.